# Visual Studio 2015 Created Old .NET Core 1.0.1 project

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-templates

I have installed .NET Core 1.1 SDK and Tooling 1.0.1 Tools Preview 2.
When I create new .NET Core project using Visual Studio 2015 it creates 1.0.1 project instead of 1.1.
Not sure how to change this ugly behavior?

Comment: Can you post the output of this command: `dotnet --version`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the templates ship with Visual Studio, which haven't received an update as part of the .NET Core release. The reason for that is probably because 1.1 is a "Current" release and 1.0.1 is an "LTS" (Long Term Support) release. Visual Studio will most likely follow the LTS releases as they provide the best and most reliable support for customers.

If you create a new application with the .NET CLI tooling (e.g. `dotnet new`), it will use the latest version. You can specify the type of the template with the `-t` switch:

- `dotnet new`: creates a console app
- `dotnet new -t web`: creates a full-blown web app
- `dotnet new -t lib`: creates a class library project

Comment: Are you sure about this? These are very bad news. If they don't support latest version they should call it preview. Yes dotnet new creates me only 2 files and I need entire web project. Not sure how to do that with CLI?

Comment: @RadenkoZec you can use `dotnet new -t web` to create a full-blown web application.

Comment: I see this behavior on my machine as well. Visual Studio does "support" the latest version in terms of building and running applications, it's just that the templates aren't updated.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.

Comment: @RadenkoZec "latest" would be a confusing thing after the introduction of LTS and Current cycles, https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/support so you should read more. The tooling around .NET Core (SDK and VS integration) is indeed just preview, but this answer roughly reflects the intention behind (till Microsoft makes a more formal announcement on their side).